# pyTelegramBotAPI и threading

Tags: python, telebot, threading

Код в упрощенном виде:

```
import threading
import telebot
from time import sleep

BOT = telebot.TeleBot("TOKEN")

def monitoring_func(chat_id):
    BOT.send_message(chat_id, 'Мониторинг включен')
    while True:
        print(f'Слежение за чатом{chat_id} работает')
        sleep(6)

@BOT.message_handler(commands=['test'])
def send_test(message):
    BOT.send_message(message.chat.id, 'TEST OK')

@BOT.message_handler(commands=['start_thread'])
def start_thread(message):
  threading.Thread(target=monitoring_func(message.chat.id)).start()

BOT.infinity_polling()
```

В чем суть - если я запускаю условное слежение командой /start_thread в двух чатах, то бот перестает реагировать на команды (например /test), только выполняя потоки. Если же только в одном чате запустить /start_thread, то бот работает корректно, параллельно выполняя поток и реагируя на команды. Как мне запускать потоки для произвольного количества чатов, чтобы они не блокировали бота?

Comment: ответ в упрощенном виде - паттерн наблюдатель, наблюдатель следит за новыми сообщениями и создает задачи воркерам(обработчикам), воркеры не следят за сообщениями, а получают задачу от наблюдателя, исполняют ее и передают ответ либо дальше (например потоку который только отправляет данные) либо сразу пользователю... Вот на почитать https://habr.com/ru/post/270339/

Answer (score 0):

Решил вопрос, добавив параметр num_threads с желаемым количеством потоков, оказалось что по дефолту там 2 потока на хэндлеры, которые исчерпывались:

```
BOT = telebot.TeleBot("TOKEN", num_threads=n)
```